# Python output does not follow order

Tags: python-3.x, printing, output

I have some practice homework with creating a function in python. One of them outputs a list of months. This is my code:

```
def outputlist(list):
    for list_output in list:
       print(list_output,end=" ")
    return list_output

def main():
    month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Setemper", "October", "November", "December"]
    print("The list of the months of the year are:", outputlist(month))

main()
```

I don't know why the output sentence does not follow in order, It should be:

"The list of the months of the year are: January February March April May June July August September October November December"

However, the output that I get is:

```
January February March April May June July August September October November December 1. The list of the months of the year are: December
```

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `print()` and `return`?

Comment: You could just use `print("The list of the months of the year are:", *month)`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm new to python, so I only know that "return" will only return the value in the function

Comment: @JohnLaRooy If I use that one, the output will look like this ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']. I don't want it to show the [] and ''

Comment: @VyQuangDao, make sure you didn't miss the `*`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Oh, I see. However, if I want to use the "ouputlist" function. How do I make it show the months behind the sentence?

Comment: @VyQuangDao, You could delete the `for` loop and just `return " ".join(list)`. Note it's recommended not to use `list` as a variable name as there is a builtin called `list`

Comment: @Vy Quang Dao check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Before the `print` function is called, all of it's arguments are evaluated.

The second argument (`outputlist(month)`) has a side-effect. It *prints* all the month names. It just returns the very last one.

When the print function is called, it's just:

```
print("The list of the months of the year are:", "December")
```

but `outputlist` has already polluted your screen by then

Answer (score 0):

The `print` in your main function is printing what is *returned* by your `outputlist` function (i.e, the final list_output, `December`). The output list function itself is being called before the print because of python's flow of execution. The print function will just print the values you pass it. In order to know what the value is of the outputlist function, it has to call it. So first python calls outputlist, then it gets the return value of that and passes it to print.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same code you can try this .
In your code you are returning only last element of list to caller. 
And Also you are printing output in `outputlist()`

```
def outputlist(list):
    print("The list of the months of the year are:")
    for list_output in list:
       print(list_output,end=" ")
     #return list_output

def main():
    month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Setemper", "October", "November", "December"]
    outputlist(month)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this

```py
def outputlist(list):
    return_var = ""
    for list_output in list: # list_output is the element of the list we currently look at
       print(list_output,end=" ")
       return_var += list_output + " " # thus printed var is the line being printed
       # the loop is at it's end, the value of list_output is discarded, 
       # and overwritten by the next element
    return return_var # to return the printed text
    return list_output # to return the last value of list_output that has not been flushed
```